# Does Collapse OS have a "WORDS" word?

Tags: forth

I have recently built Dusk OS (a Collapse OS derivative).

I was surprised to see that it does not have a `WORDS` word.

Does Collapse OS or Dusk OS have a word that shows all words in the dictionary?

Comment: Try `VLIST`, used in older versions of Forth instead of `WORDS`.

Comment: @TlsChris Dusk OS is not FIG based.